# Are different equations of the constant of integration equatable?

Tags: integration

I was thinking of some problems with nuclear physics. I need to derive a function of displacement and time for a particle colliding with is antiparticle. The two particles were at rest when they were separated at displacement $a$ away from each other. All what i need is to detremine the value of $c$ . $a$ and $b$ are known. I  arrived to such  equation, 
$$m\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2=\frac{ℏcα}{2x}-2δ(2x)+A$$

this is the solution i get after multiplying both sides by $2(dx/dt)$ and integrating with respect to $t$ for the  equation below
$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\frac{ℏcα}{(2x)^2}-\frac{dδ(2x)}{dx}$$

$δ(x)$ is a function of $x$. $A$ in the first equation is the constant of integration. Here i have two different boundary conditions;

$(1)$ when $x=a$, $dx/dt=0$, hence,
$$A=2δ(2a)-\frac{ℏcα}{2a}$$

$(2)$ when $x=b/2$, $dx/dt=1-1/c^2$, whereas, $c$ is a non-zero constant,therefore

$$A=\left(1-\frac{1}{c^2}\right)+2δ(b)-\frac{ℏcα}{b}$$
I originally thought that I've to formulate the displacement-time function in order to determine the value of $c$. But after i saw the two equations of $A$ above, i equated them to each other and calculated the value of $c$ easily. This convenience is too good that made me start to think that equating different equations of the constant of integration is wrong. Is it really wrong?? or its just me thinking too much??

Comment: How did you multiply $y'^{2}$ by $2y'$ and integrate to get $y''$?

Comment: No @Mattos it's the reverse, the first equation is the solution of the second equation, i was clear in my question.

Comment: You're right, I read the question incorrectly. Also, why does $2x' (\delta(2x))'$ integrate to $2 \delta 2(x)$?

Comment: $\int(2x′(δ(2x))′)dt=2\int((δ(2x))′dx=δ(2x)$@Mattos

Comment: Are different equations of the constant of integration equatable?@Mattos